# Immutable Global objects for multi-tenancy

Tags: nashorn

We run a multi-tenant environment where users can execute arbitrary scripts using Nashorn. Performance is extremely important for us, so we would rather not create a new `SimpleScriptContext` object (or even a new `SimpleBindings` object) on each script eval.

However, this leaves us open to people modifying the global context, which then must be reused for other users / executions. E.g. `Math.min = function(a,b) { return 42; }`.

Freezing the `Math` object is a partial solution, but it seems to slow down script execution, and we have to be extremely diligent to make sure we do this everywhere. Similarly, creating a new `SimpleBindings` object to replace the `ENGINE_SCOPE` bindings on each execution is a big performance hit.

Are there any options available to us to lock the Global state? Or anything that I haven't thought of?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of "performance" are you talking about? Is it feasible to open a new SimpleScriptContext for each user (instead of each script evaluation)?

Comment: Actually yes, that's one of our fallback options. This will be a tradeoff for us (the possibility that we have to keep large numbers of these in memory).